# looping through images with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a little javascript routine I am trying to write but after staring at it for hours, I can't get it to work, so its probably something trivial.
I have a series of 11 images called dd0.jpg, dd1.jpg ....dd10.jpg and I'm trying to loop through them, and then when I get to dd10.jpg, the process reverses and then goes back to dd0.jpg

The javascript code is

```
<script>

var ddimagearray = [];

var ddn = 0;
var incrementing = true;

for(var i =0; i<11; i++)
{
    ddimagearray[i] = new Image();
    ddimagearray[i].src =  "/dd/dd" + i + ".jpg";
}

var ddname = document.getElementById("ddimage");


var myVar = setInterval(function(){ changeimage() }, 100); // Milliseconds



function changeimage() 
{

    if (incrementing == true)
    {

        ddname.src = ddimagearray[ddn].src;

        ddn++;

        if(ddn == 14)
        {
            incrementing = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {

        ddname.src = ddimagearray[ddn].src;

        ddn--;

        if(ddn == 0)
        {
            incrementing = true;
        }

    }



}

</script>

On a test page I have <center><img src="/dd/dd0.jpg" id="ddimage" class=ddimage/></center><script src="dd.js"></script>
```

Can anyone see anything desperately wrong?

Comment: And what’s it doing instead of what you want it to do? Do any errors get thrown? Is the problem maybe something to do with creating 11 images and only changing direction at #15?

Comment: No errors as far as I can see. Its showing up /dd/dd0.jpg and nothing else

Comment: You should consider rewriting this as a for loop.

Comment: What's the problem? You want to set the images and some time interval to changeimage method?

Comment: Yes thats right. As I said I want it to increment through the images, reach the end and then decrement, and then go through the process again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `14` to `10` in `incrementing == true` case, 14 will throw exception `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined` because ddimagearray have only 10 items.

```js
var ddimagearray = [];

var ddn = 0;
var incrementing = true;

for(var i =0; i<11; i++)
{
    ddimagearray[i] = new Image();
    ddimagearray[i].src =  "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/" + i;
}

var ddname = document.getElementById("ddimage");


var myVar = setInterval(function(){ changeimage() }, 100); // Milliseconds



function changeimage() 
{

    if (incrementing == true)
    {

        ddname.src = ddimagearray[ddn].src;

        ddn++;

        if(ddn == 10)
        {
            incrementing = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {

        ddname.src = ddimagearray[ddn].src;

        ddn--;

        if(ddn == 0)
        {
            incrementing = true;
        }

    }



}
```

```html
<img id="ddimage" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/0/"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed this (the number of looping images was reduced from 14 to 10)

Comment: It would be better to use the length of the array `ddimagearray.length` instead of a magic number.

Comment: @EventHorizon maybe the problem is in different place, do you have any exceptions in console?

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle of your code works fine(except of-course for the limit of ddn as @jcubic posted).

Is this a simplified version of your actual code?
Are you getting any errors?

your problem might be that `ddimagearray` is not in scope of the `changeImage` function so `ddname.src = ddimagearray[ddn].src;` throws `uncaught typeError`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code is the line:

var myVar = setInterval(function(){ changeimage() }, 100); // Milliseconds

Replace it with the following and see what happens:

var myVar = setInterval("changeimage()", 100); // Milliseconds